# Имитация зажатой клавиши в ubuntu

Tags: linux

Нужно что-бы клавиша (допустим W) всегда была зажата. В windows это делалось простым вызовом api keybd_event('W', 0,0,0) или посылкой сообщения окну SendMessage(handle, WM_KEYDOWN, 'W', 0);.

Comment: xdotool пробовали? Это стандартное решение.

Comment: а ежели надо именно с помощью функций (понятно, на си), то вот к примеру: [sending fake keypress event to a window using xlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30413316/4827341)

Comment: Крайне нехорошо задавать вопросы [повторно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/695268/%d0%98%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b8-%d0%b2-ubuntu). Прямо скажем: ***спамить*** сайт одним и тем же вопросом. Настоятельно рекомендую не делать так, чтобы не пришлось объясняться с модераторами.

Answer (score 1):

Вот как с помощью Python,ибо он заранее установлен на linux. 
Заранее нужно будет установить pyautogui через терминал командой `pip install pyautogui`,если вы собираетесь использовать версию 2.7 или `pip3 install pyautogui` если хотите использовать 3.x версию пайтона. :

```
import pyautogui

while True:
    pyautogui.press('w')
```